# Relacionamento em MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Galera boa tarde, estou precisando de uma ajuda de alguem que tenha experiência com MongoDB para me tirar uma dúvida. 
Estou estudando sobre o MongoDB e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Tenho 2 Collections:

Clientes e Usuários

Cada cliente tem sua lista de usuários referenciados pelos respectivos ObjectID.
Cada usuário tem um campo Proprietário para identificar o Cliente que ele pertence.

A questão é que eu preciso criar uma estrutura onde um cliente possa ser pai de outros clientes, ou seja no meu objeto cliente eu terei uma propriedade [Filhos],
onde irá conter o ObjectID de cada Filho, e terá tbm o campo proprietário para identificar se ele é filho de alguem.

O meu problema é: Como filtrar todos os usuários que são meus e os usuários que são dos meus filhos e filhos dos meus filhos e sucessivamente.

Preciso criar essa arquitetura no MongoDB e não faço ideia de como faze-la, estou utilizando Node.JS + Mongoose + MongoDB.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando uma modelagem sql em um banco nosql.
O correto é você não ter referencias e sim os objetos propriamente ditos, invés de armazenar um id de um objeto pai em um objeto filho, colocar diretamente uma collection de filhos neste objeto pai. 
Em nosql não existe joins ele é bem diferente que o sql convencional,para fazer "joins" em casos simples você usaria o aggregation: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/ 
e em casos mais complexos o map-reduce: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

ambos são bem mais performáticos que os joins convencionais do sql, porem não são tão simples como o mesmo.