# Como relacionar duas tabelas "models" em MongoDD com mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodemon, módulo-ecmascript

Eu tenho dois `model` no meu bd.

```
const Corporacao = mongoose.model('Corporacao',{
    nome: String,
    razao: String,
    cnpj: String,
    status: Boolean,
})
```

```
const Unidade = mongoose.model('Unidade',{
    nome: String,
    corporacao_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Corporacao'},
    razao: String,
    status: Boolean,
})
```

Quero que **UNIDADE** tenha um campo (**corporacao_ID**) que seja relacionada a uma **CORPORACAO**.

**No caso eu quero que toda UNIDADE tenha uma CORPORACAO relacionada onde eu farei o controle delas**

**RESPOSTA**
Acrescentei a linha:

```
corporacao_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Corporacao'},
```

E o problema foi resolvido, obrigaod @CmteCardeal

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Relacionamento em MongoDB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118068/relacionamento-em-mongodb)

Comment: Voce pode usar o [`ref`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) para criar "relacionamentos" entre documentos. No seu caso, teria que fazer algo do tipo: `corporacao_ID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Corporacao'
    }`. Fique atento que se suas entidades tem muitos relacionamentos e dependecias, mongodb provavelmente não seria o banco ideal pra isso.

Comment: @CmteCardeal deu certo, muito obrigado.